# Unable to include a stylesheet link in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, ruby-on-rails-5, stylesheet, assets

I'm having a problem declaring a stylesheet tag in my Rails 5 view.  I have this

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'form', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

and then in my config/initializers/assets.rb I have this at the end

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( form.css )
```

My file is located at app/assets/stylesheets/form.css.scss, but even after restarting my server, I get the error below

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled in MyEvents#index

Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( form.css )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server
```

How do I get Rails to include this stylesheet on my page?

Comment: Try restarting your server.

Comment: How are you running your server in production? Do you precompile the assets? Does it work locally in development?

Comment: @Leito, I should have mentioned I'm running on my local machine and intend for this to be for development.  I'm starting my server like so, "rails s -b 127.0.0.1".

Comment: If you added your file to app/assets/stylesheets, it should automatically get added to the asset pipeline. You shouldn't need to do any other modifying.

Comment: Then why am I getting the error?  What other information can I provide to help here?

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the stylesheet tag to simply

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'form' %>
```

then eveerything worked.